# re-order mysql table rows irrespective of chronological order

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

There's something i'm curious about. Is it possible to re-arrange database table rows using eloquent...? Here's the idea below:

```
id    |    key    |    name
---------------------------
1     |   ais     |    mike
2     |   ais     |    tom
3     |   ajk     |    nick
4     |   ajk     |    john
5     |   cyj     |    merry
6     |   cyj     |    tobais
```

I want to reorder the table rows above using the key column but with the chronological order of the keys ignored. See the second table below:

```
id    |    key    |    name
---------------------------
3     |   ajk     |    nick
4     |   ajk     |    john
1     |   ais     |    mike
2     |   ais     |    tom
5     |   cyj     |    merry
6     |   cyj     |    tobais
```

## edit

basically, i'm expecting and array from an external API. I'm to reorder the table based on the order of this array. For example if the array comes like this: ["cyj, ais"], then, i must reorder the table such that rows with key "cyj" comes first and rows with key "ais" follows

Comment: `select * from my_table order by key`?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes. Order by key. But is it possible for me to define how the order is done...?